# Hypernym for "boys only", "girls only", and "co-ed"

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

What word would be used on a form where one is asked to stipulate if a school accepts only boys, girls or is co-ed?

We are creating the form, and the word I am looking for would be used for a drop down that has the three options "boys only", "girls only", "co-ed".

Comment: Single-sex, probably, but it's not clear from your question whether you writing the form itself or filling it in. That may make a difference.

Comment: Too bad *student sexual orientation* is already taken.

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but when faced with this problem in general -- creating a multiple-choice question on a form where I can't think of an appropriate label -- I often just don't put any label, just give the options.

Comment: I don't think "hypernym" is the right word here; a hypernym of "boys only", "girls only", and "co-ed" would be an adjective that described any school that is any of those things. That is, it could fit into the sentence, "All boys-only schools, all girls-only schools, and all co-ed schools are _____ schools."

Comment: +1 @ruakh - So a better term than "hypernym" might be "category", "heading", "tag" or "label" (espec. given that the context is an e-form)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Co-education* (and *co-ed*) is the term used to highlight a system which is now considered the norm for education. Since this is a questionnaire, you have the option of using one-word questions.

> *Coeducational?*
>
> - Yes
> - No — boys only
> - No — girls only

Answer (score 9):

You could use one of the following phrases

> - *Enrollment Gender*
> - *Student Gender*
> - *Student Body Gender*
> - *Student Gender(s)*
> - *Student Body Gender(s)*

Answer (score 7):

How about "School demographic" or "Gender demographic"?

Answer (score 5):

I can't think of a term like that, if one exists, but you could use something like "Student Body" or "Student Population" or maybe "School Classification".

If you want to sound more formal, I think the commonly accepted terms for the three classifications are "All-boys", "All-girls", and "Co-educational".

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the use of the word *environment*. If it is too broad, you could narrow it down further to something along the lines of *school environment*, *educational environment*, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

"Enrollment Population" is brief and avoids both the dicey "sex" and the incorrect "gender".

Comment: Why is "gender" incorrect? Alone, it's a little puzzling, but others have suggested companion words.

Comment: I've learned that 'gender' is strictly a linguistic term, describing the gender of nouns, adjectives, etc., and that 'sex' is correct for humans and other living creatures.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use *gender restriction*.

Answer (score 1):

**"Gender allowed"**? (accepted? permitted?)

It's not very smooth but I can't think of anything better.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is "Gender of intake" — bit wordy though, I confess.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to add to the "gender" terms, all of which I consider "warm," but the term I would use is *gender specific.* That is, the school specifics its gender "preference," (or lack thereof in the case of co-ed).